# Use Google Analytics UTM codes and referral at same time

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, tracking, affiliate

I have two different affiliate networks sending me traffic, all tracked using UTM codes;

**network A**

- `medium=affiliates`
- `source=affiliatenetworkA`

**network B**

- `medium=affiliates`
- `source=affiliatenetworkB`

If I want to also dynamically track the individual URLs of the sites within each network, how can I do that (without having to give each site a separate UTM code)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a new line of code, wouldn't it be easier to look at Referrar URL report filtered to networkA and networkB Domains?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to set the one of the UTM parameters to be the referrer.  For example to set the keyword parameter with the referrer you would use:

```
ga('set', 'campaignKeyword', document.referrer);
```